# How to Trim below highlighted lines from Shell output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

How to Trim below highlighted lines from Shell output. Source shell program is below the output.

```
$ ./checkhome.sh
```

> **The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle**
>
> Connecting Database DB1 is Installed on
>   /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0
>
> **The Oracle base has been changed from /opt/oracle to /opt/oracle/app/oracle**
>
> Connecting Database DB2 is Installed on
>   /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0
>
> **The Oracle base has been changed from /opt/oracle/app/oracle to /opt/oracle**
>
> Connecting Database DB3 is Installed on
>   /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0
>
> $
>   **

#### Contents of script

```
$ cat checkhome.sh

DB=`ps -ef |grep pmon | grep -v grep |awk '{print $8}'|cut -d '_' -f3`

for i in `echo $DB`    
do    
    export ORACLE_SID=$i    
    export ORAENV_ASK=NO    
    . oraenv $i    
    echo "Connecting Database $i is Installed on $ORACLE_HOME"    
done

exit
```

Comment: Are those messages printed to standard error or standard output? Does `./checkhome.sh | grep -v "^The Oracle base"` work? If not, does `./checkhome.sh 2>/dev/null` work?

Comment: Thanks Terdon../checkhome.sh | grep -v "^The Oracle base"

Comment: Thanks Terdon,
this works fine. 
./checkhome.sh | grep -v "^The Oracle base"
is there any way to supress this from the script.
The Oracle base has*

Comment: You're welcome. I posted that as an answer, please remember to click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site.

Comment: You can use whatever string you like, to remove lines starting with `The oracle base has`, add `has` to the grep: `grep -v "^The Oracle base has"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to filter out text is to use reverse `grep` (from `man grep`):

```
   -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
          is specified by POSIX.)
```

In your case, you can exclude all lines starting with "The Oracle base" by using `^` to match the beginning of the line only and `-v` to print non matching lines:

```
./checkhome.sh | grep -v "^The Oracle base"
```

Note that in some cases, these messages are printed to standard error instead of standard output which means that simply redirecting STDERR to `/dev/null` will be enough:

```
./checkhome.sh 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ./checkhome.sh 2>/dev/null -- Not working    
$ ./checkhome.sh 2>/dev/null
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
Connecting Database DB1is Installed on /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0
The Oracle base has been changed from /opt/oracle to /opt/oracle/app/oracle
Connecting Database DB2 is Installed on /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0
The Oracle base has been changed from /opt/oracle/app/oracle to /opt/oracle
Connecting Database DB3 is Installed on /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0

Comment: @ABULKASHIM Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Anyway, the `2>/dev/null` is not relevant here, I included it for any other users who might face a similar problem. If the `grep -v` works, that means the messages are in the standard output so just use `grep -v "^The Oracle base"`.